# Unable to retrieve arraylist elements on icefaces(jsf) xhtml page

Tags: java, jsf, icefaces

I am having `HTML` table on my page and am trying to populate it with some data from my managed bean, my `xhtml` page looks like:

```
       <ice:panelGrid columns="2">
            <ice:panelGrid>
                <ice:outputText value="Properties:" style="text-align:left;font-size:20px;"></ice:outputText>
                <ice:selectManyListbox id="CriteriaListbox" style="width: 200px; height: 250px; " partialSubmit="true">
                 <p:selectItem value="#{beanInfo.properties}"/>
                </ice:selectManyListbox>
            </ice:panelGrid>
      </ice:panelGrid>
```

My managed bean looks like:

```
public ArrayList<String> getProperties()
{
    return properties;
}
```

and in constructor am populating `properties` as shown:

```
public BeanInfo(){
   createProperties();
}

createProperties(){
    ArrayList<String> properties = new ArrayList<String>();
    properties.add("roi");
    properties.add("val");
}
```

Am new to `jsf` and `icefaces` and so not sure what is the issue in here. Any suggestions?

**Update**

So there is nothing in my table but am getting `java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to javaax.faces.model.SelectItem` exception.

**Update 2**

This is the exception am getting after [Nikita's Approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9723504/164299) and updating my `JSF` version from `Mojarra-2.0.3` to `Mojarra-2.1.7`, any suggestions.

```
Error Rendering View[/admin/Template.xhtml]: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to javax.faces.model.SelectItem
    at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.MenuRenderer.countSelectOptionsRecursive(MenuRenderer.java:440) [:]
    at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.MenuRenderer.renderSelect(MenuRenderer.java:366) [:]
    at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.MenuRenderer.encodeEnd(MenuRenderer.java:108) [:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875) [:2.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.DomBasicRenderer.encodeParentAndChildren(DomBasicRenderer.java:359) [:]
    at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:197) [:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845) [:2.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.DomBasicRenderer.encodeParentAndChildren(DomBasicRenderer.java:347) [:]
    at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:197) [:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845) [:2.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779) [:2.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782) [:2.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782) [:2.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782) [:2.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402) [:2.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125) [:2.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121) [:2.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [:2.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [:2.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) [:2.1.7-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:324) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.0.0.Final]
```

**Update 3: Current xhtml**

```
  <ice:panelGrid columns="2">
            <ice:panelGrid>
                <ice:outputText value="Properties:" style="text-align:left;font-size:20px;"></ice:outputText>
                <ice:selectManyListbox id="CriteriaListbox" style="width: 200px; height: 250px; " partialSubmit="true">
                 <p:selectItems value="#{bookBeanInfo.properties}"
                                  var="property"
                                  itemValue="#{property}"
                                  itemLabel="#{property}"/>

                </ice:selectManyListbox>

            </ice:panelGrid>

            <ice:panelGrid>
                <ice:outputText value="Name:" style="text-align:left;font-size:20px;" id="bookName"></ice:outputText>
            </ice:panelGrid>
            <ice:panelGrid>
                <ice:inputText id="NameInputText" style="width: 195px;" value="#{bookBeanInfo.bookName}"></ice:inputText>
            </ice:panelGrid>
```

**Update 4: Namespace declaration**

```
html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:icecore="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/core"
xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:ace="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/components"
xmlns:p="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ice-cc="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces-composite-comps">
```

**Update5**

I was able to fix the exception by using array list of SelectItem types rather then String so in my bean, I have:

```
createProperties(){
    ArrayList<SelectItem> properties = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    properties.add(new SelectItem("roi", "roi"));
    properties.add(new SelectItem("val"."val"));
}
```

and in my `xhtml` page, i have to use `selectItems` instead of `selectItem` as on my xhtml page am expecting collection and so need to use `selectItems` to iterate through them:

```
 <ice:panelGrid columns="2">
        <ice:panelGrid>
            <ice:outputText value="Properties:" style="text-align:left;font-size:20px;"></ice:outputText>
            <ice:selectManyListbox id="CriteriaListbox" style="width: 200px; height: 250px; " partialSubmit="true">
             <p:selectItems value="#{beanInfo.properties}"/>
            </ice:selectManyListbox>
        </ice:panelGrid>
  </ice:panelGrid>
```

Comment: Can you show you current xhtml?

Comment: What is `p:selectItems`? Is it really JSF standard `selectItems`? Can you show declaration for `p` namespace?

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov: Updated question with namespace declaration

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov: This is really wierd, isn't it?

Comment: Ok. Can you then say your icefaces lib version? :)

Comment: icefaces lib version 2.0

Comment: It is weird, because when I check sources here http://www.icesoft.org/community/source-code.jsf Only versions 1.x has package `com.icesoft`.

Comment: Ok, I found it. http://sventon.icesoft.org//svn/showfile.svn;jsessionid=03812ECBE55A60FFD633FD3579BF4CB6?path=/icefaces2/tags/icefaces-2.0.0-final/icefaces/compat/core/src/main/java/com/icesoft/faces/renderkit/dom_html_basic/MenuRenderer.java&revision=HEAD&name=repo but I still don't understand why is it failing.

Comment: hmm...ok...even looking for reason why is causing the issue

Comment: If i follow steps mentioned here :http://hobione.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/jsf-fselectitem-vs-javaxfacesmodelselectitem/ then it seems to be working but i get result as `[0,1,2,3]` etc format rather then in list form format, can't explain this really.

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov: I have another question related to display of data, http://stackoverflow.com/q/9728701/164299

Comment: You can try to update to newer icefaces lib :)

Comment: i have latest `icefaces` lib, i believe :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is causing ClasscastException because in constructor of bean you are making a collection of type String i.e. `Arraylist<String>` while JSF uses collection of type SelectItem i.e. `Arraylist<SelectItems>`. When with current setting page renders it thows ClasscastException, which s obvious.

**Posible Fix:** 
 **(1)** change the type of collection in constructor. Make it
    `Arraylist<SelectItem>`
 **(2)** `<f:selectItem>` (as suggested by others) should work. But if it doesn't then try below:

```
 <ice:selectOneMenu value="myProperties">  
   <ice:selectItems value="#{beanInfo.properties}" />
 </ice:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: What is `myProperties` being referred in here?

Comment: Also is that by default that `JSF` uses collection of `ArrayList<SelectItem>` type?

Comment: @Rachel : `myProperties`  is just a text which will appear as a label on your dropdown.

Comment: I do not need dropdown, i need to have listbox in which i have listed all elements of arraylist returned from managedbean

Comment: @Rachel: to have listBox just change the componect name. So in your XHTML you will use something like this  `<ice:selectOneListbox>` in place of `<ice:selectOneMenu>`

Comment: If you see am using `<ice:selectManyListbox>` component, i guess that should work?

Comment: Yes, that should work. Question: Are you able to get rid of that ClasscastException?

Comment: No, still having same issues  `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to javax.faces.model.SelectItem
`

Comment: right now using ` <p:selectItems value="#{bookBeanInfo.Properties}"/>` and this throws that exception.

Comment: @Rachal: Did you updated your BeanInfo class to have ArrayList<SelectItem>?  Also make sure you are updating the return type of getter, I mean `public ArrayList<SelectItem> getProperties()
{
    return properties;
}`

Comment: First get rid of class cast exception by changing the (1) return type of getter (2) and change the Arraylist<selectItem> then give a try.

Comment: @Rachel: Look carefully at @roel reply. Make you you are storing only selectItem in you properties collection. SelectItem is similar to `Map` . So you need to store in form of Key/value pairs.   LIke this `properties.add(new SelectItem("ONE","roi"));

properties.add(new SelectItem("TWO","var"));`

Comment: I was not adding it as Map but like list.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8971/discussion-between-rachel-and-vyoma)

Comment: OP is using JSF2. The `SelectItem` restriction should not be anymore necessary. This is most likely another ICEfaces specific quirk. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use namespace `p` for `<p:selectItem value="#{beanInfo.properties}"/>`? `p` is usually primefaces components, I'm not sure it is good practice to mix component libraries. Try jsf's standard `<f:selectItems value="#{beanInfo.properties"/>`
Note, that you should use selectItems not selectItem when you use list as value.

**Updated**
Try

```
<f:selectItems value="#{beanInfo.properties}"
               var="property"
               itemValue="#{property}"
               itemLabel="#{property}"/>
```

Comment: Did you try selectItems, not selectItem?

Comment: why are you using var as `property`?

Comment: I use it because jsf (or icefaces) need to get collection of `SelectItem` objects. You can either pass collection of them in `value` property as @roel suggested or you can pass collection of plain java objects and use `var`, `itemValue`, `itemLabel` to create these `SelectItems` by jsf.

Comment: so you can also have propteries or test instead of property for var, right?

Comment: also, am not sure why am getting `java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to javaax.faces.model.SelectItem`, have you encountered this issue in the past?

Comment: I can only imagine that it sees selectItem not selectItems and think it is single value and tries to convert your array to single `SelectItem`. Do you have stacktrace?

Comment: I have modified my `xhtml` pages per comments, it is building right now, I will update question in couple mins.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8938/discussion-between-nikita-beloglazov-and-rachel)

Comment: Thanks for your continued efforts :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use selectitem in stead of string in your getter

```
public ArrayList<SelectItem> getProperties() {
   return properties;
}
```

and fill your properties with selectitems

```
properties.add(new SelectItem(<the value>, <text to display>));
```

Comment: you should use  <p:selectItems value="#{beanInfo.properties}"/>
And in the meantime change the namespace to the standard use of f and p    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core". It then becomes <f:selectItems value="#{beanInfo.properties}"/>

Comment: this does not work and throws `classcastexception mentioned in update2`

Comment: you also changed to arraylist<selectItem>?